# Tomcat throws AbstractMethodError for WebSocketServlet.createWebSocketInbound() when custom servlet runs

Tags: java, websocket, tomcat7

I work on a project in which I need to create a real time web application. I've developed a small program to test WebSockets with Apache Tomcat, but it doesn't work and instead throws an `AbstractMethodError` exception. The servlet compiles and the web application deploys fine.

Here's the servlet's code.

```
public class TestWebSocket extends WebSocketServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected boolean verifyOrigin(String origin) {
        System.out.println("Origin: {}" + origin);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected StreamInbound createWebSocketInbound(String subProtocol, HttpServletRequest request) {
        return new WebSocketConnection();
    }

    private static class WebSocketConnection extends MessageInbound {

        @Override
        protected void onOpen(WsOutbound outbound) {
            System.out.println("Conexión abierta");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onClose(int status) {
            System.out.println("Conexión cerrada");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onBinaryMessage(ByteBuffer byteBuffer) throws IOException {
            System.out.println("No se soportan mensajes binarios");
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("No se soportan mensajes binarios");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onTextMessage(CharBuffer charBuffer) throws IOException {
            final String user = charBuffer.toString();
            System.out.println("Mensaje recibido: {}" + user);
            getWsOutbound().writeTextMessage(CharBuffer.wrap("Hola " + user + " desde WebSocket"));
        }
    }
}
```

Here goes the deployment descriptor - `web.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>TestWebSocket</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>TestWebSocket</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.test.TestWebSocket</servlet-class>
  </servlet> 
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>TestWebSocket</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/testWebSocket</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

And the client code - `testSocket.js`:

```
/*
 * For Testing websockets
 */
$(function(){

    console.log("URL :" + 'ws://' + location.host  + '/TestTomcatWebSocket/testWebSocket');
    var ws = new WebSocket('ws://' + location.host  + '/TestTomcatWebSocket/testWebSocket');

    ws.onopen = function() {
        console.log("Websocket Ready!!");
        sendMessage();
    };

    ws.onmessage= function(data) {
        console.log("message received : " + data);
    };

    function sendMessage() { ws.send("Test"); };
});
```

Upon execution the application finishes with the following `java.lang.AbstractMethodError` exception:

```
INFO: Server startup in 495 ms
Origin: {}http://localhost:8080
Dec 17, 2012 1:58:51 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [TestWebSocket] in context with path [/TestTomcatWebSocket] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.catalina.websocket.WebSocketServlet.createWebSocketInbound(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/catalina/websocket/StreamInbound;
    at org.apache.catalina.websocket.WebSocketServlet.doGet(WebSocketServlet.java:125)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I use Apache Tomcat 7.0.33.

Comment: Do you have Tomcat JARs in `WEB-INF/lib`?

Comment: should I include it explicitly when tomcat have it already in its library folder?

Comment: No, I would not bundle Tomcat JARs in `WEB-INF/lib`. This way you should automatically get them from Tomcat.

Comment: i figured it out further that when i export the websocket above code as war file in eclipse and run it manually on tomcat. it runs fine. but when I run it with eclipse its throwing the above exception. Can you tell why is that so?

Comment: problem solved. basically i was using the older version of eclipse which configures tomcat according to tomcat's earlier configuration for running tomcat inside it. So when i used eclipse's latest version JUNO it configured it with tomcats latest configuration which includes websocket configuration in catilina.policy

    // Applications using WebSocket need to be able to access this package
    permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "accessClassInPackage.org.apache.catalina.websocket";

Comment: @AliRaza you should turn the recent comment as a response and accept it so the question will have an answer.

Comment: It also a kind of weird to see `web.xml` with `xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd` while `xsi:schemaLocation` points to `web-app_3_0.xsd` and `version="3.0"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved. basically i was using the older version of eclipse which configures tomcat according to tomcat's earlier configuration for running tomcat inside it. So when i used eclipse's latest version JUNO it configured it with tomcats latest configuration which includes websocket configuration in catilina.policy file.

// Applications using WebSocket need to be able to access this package permission `java.lang.RuntimePermission "accessClassInPackage.org.apache.catalina.websocket";`